# CollectionViewSource not populating datagrid when string is empty in search box

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am using collectionviewsource to search the datagrid in my wpf application. I am populating my datagrid from database using the entity framework. Everything works fine except search function. I am using textchanged event and collectionviewsource to search for text from datagrid itemsource. What happens is i can do search and datagrid is filtering the data while typing in the searchbox(searchbox here is textbox), but when emptying the searchbox the datagrid must populate all the rows, but this were i am having issue. It was show the last search filter. here is the code below. Please help me guys..

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            textSearch = sender as TextBox;
            filterText = textSearch.Text;

            var cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgDetailedRecordList.ItemsSource);

            if (filterText != null)
            {
                cv.Filter = o =>
                {
                    var emp = o as DetailedReportInventoryTableItems;
                    return (emp.product_name.ToLower().ToString().Contains(filterText.ToLower().ToString())
                    || emp.emp_no.ToLower().ToString().Contains(filterText.ToLower().ToString())
                    );
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May the issue is with already assigned filter. you have to reset the filter if `txtSearch.Text` is `String.Empty`. Try modifying your code like the following:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgDetailedRecordList.ItemsSource);
     if (txtSearch.Text != String.Empty)
     {
         textSearch = sender as TextBox;
         filterText = textSearch.Text;  
         if (filterText != null)
         {
             // Existing filter here     
         }
     }
     else
     {
        cv.Filter = null;
     }
}
```

I haven't tested the code so, Please let me know if it works.

Few Additional notes for improvement:

- `.ToLower()` returns a string so there is no need to append with a `.ToString()` there.
- if you are not sure about the datatype of `emp.product_name` then you can use `.ToString()` after that not after `.ToLower()`.
- So the code will be like `emp.product_name.ToString().ToLower().`